# What measuring unit is used for file sizes in javascript?

Tags: javascript

am trying to validate file size on the client side before uploading to server. However I think i need to calculate max-size in javascript.

So how do i write **4MB** in javascript ?
I would also want to know basically in what measuring unit is javascript calculated in terms of file size.

below is my colde:

```
//Grab the file list
        var files   =   e.target.files;
        $.each(files,function(i,file){

        //check for the correct file extensiton
        var n   = file.name,
            s   = file.size
            t   = file.type;
        if(s > 4MB){

            console.log("File is greater than 4MB");

   }
}
```

Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Javascript has no concept of "units", just like any other programming language. It only knows about "numbers". It is up to the programmer to interpret those numbers.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Taking a simple look at the content of `s` would have shown that...

Comment: 4MB = 4 * 1024 * 1024

Comment: You _can_ use some library like `jquery` for that, but it is not worth the effort. What is a MB? 1024*1024 bytes. So why can't you simply write `if(s > 4*1024*1024)` ? You might want to work with MiB instead using a base of `1000`...

Comment: [Megabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte)

Comment: good answer. so how many bytes makes one megabits in javascript ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The file size is measured in bytes - do this:

```js
if (s > 4 * 1024 * 1024)
    alert("Too big");
```

Answer (score 7):

Your question is not about JavaScript itself, but the File API.

See the documentation for [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). It doesn't list the size property but it does say:

> The File interface also inherits properties from the Blob interface

So see the documentation for [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

> **Blob.size Read only**
>   The size, in bytes, of the data contained in the Blob object.

Thus the value is given in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html 5 [**FILE API**](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) or [**Blob.size**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size)

The `Blob.size` property returns the size in bytes of the Blob or a File.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" multiple id="myfileinput">
```

**JS**

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");
// files is a FileList object
var files = fileInput.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  console.log(files[i].name + " has a size of " + files[i].size + " Bytes");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(s / (1024 * 1024) > 4)
```

FILE gives you size in bytes and hence the above condition will do the check you require

Answer (score -1):

Just little more detail

1 kb = 1024 bytes
1mb = 1024 kb  or (1024*1014) bytes

so 4 mb is 4 * 1024 *1024 (in terms of bytes)

Here kb is kilobyte, mg is megabyte