# else not change and read with image size upload jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check the image size.

When I upload an image, it is showing me a message if the image file size is larger than 1 MB, but when I upload an image with a file size less than 1 MB, the message is not hiding.

Here is my code:

**html**

```
    <input id="image-file" type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <div class="alert alert-danger imgSize">fdfdfdfdfdf</div>
```

**js**

```
 $(document).on('change' ,'#image-file',function() {
   if(this.files[0].size >= 1024){

     $(".imgSize").fadeIn();

   }else{

     $(".imgSize").fadeOut();
     alert("sdsd");

   }
 });
```

https://codepen.io/hesham-farag/pen/YJoKwm

Comment: Because size unit is byte so you should use `this.files[0].size >= 1048576`

Comment: 2mb  = 2097152   Right ?

Comment: Yeah, right. 2M = 2*1048576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What measuring unit is used for file sizes in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305186/what-measuring-unit-is-used-for-file-sizes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

In **js**, file size is measured in bytes:

Try the following code:

```js
$(document).on('change' ,'#image-file',function() {
   if(this.files[0].size >= (1 * 1024 * 1024)){
     
     $(".imgSize").html("Image size is <b>more</b> than 1 mb.");
     
   }else{
     
     $(".imgSize").html("Image size is <b>less</b> than 1 mb.");
     
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Upload image:<input id="image-file" type="file" name="file" />

<br><br>Message: 
<div class="imgSize"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery is right, the problem is in the file size.
You are receiving a value in bytes and comparing to another in kilobytes, that's why the calculus seems wrong.

Just change the value to 1048576 (equivalent to 1MB) and it should work.

Comment: `1024 * 1024` is equal to 1048576. What is 125000?

Comment: i think 1MB = 1048576  as comment up

Comment: I used an automatic conversion. I updated the answer.